# Automatic creation of Internet Archive Wayback Machine links for external links

Tags: discussion, feature-request, hyperlinks, external-links, archive

As per [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer):

> Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context
>   around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is
>   and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an
>   important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes
>   permanently offline.

But when all relevant info would/could be transfered from the linked website to the answer, the link would nearly be irrelevant. But it is relevant, at least as a source. Then we still have the danger of a link becoming invalid for two reasons:

- The website might become inaccessible in the future
- The content of the website might change in the future

Therefore, it is important to preserve that source in a way. With some luck, there might be an old snapshot in the [Internet Archive Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/). But if it was not created on the same day as a post referencing a website, then you can never be sure it still points to the intended content.

When I insert links into a post, I often go to the IAWM and create current snapshots of the links. But then I am not sure, if I should already use those links inside my posts or still the original ones or adding both - the IAWM links probably as an additional reference at the end. All in all, some effort.

As there is already a comfortable button to insert hyperlinks, I am asking myself:

**Would it not be a nice feature, if this button used the API of the [IAWM](http://web.archive.org/) and created snapshots of those links automatically to preserve the content for the future and added those links instead of OR in addition to the original links?**

This feature would definitely consume more ressources than the process of hyperlink insertion does now. But may be it is nothing to speak of nowadays and would be an effective way to preserve information on the internet.

Comment: I'm not sure how the wayback machine preserves pages, but I guess it'll only preserve the visible html / css (?), so this won't work for every link (e.g. playgrounds, ...). Maybe dead links could be automatically migrated to a wayback link using a bot that goes through all links (similarily to the research Andy did in the linked thread)

Comment: The linked thread indeed shares my intention. Didn't find that on my search.

Comment: Some sites have requested that their content is not archived ... "Site owners might have also requested that their sites be excluded from the Wayback Machine." from [Using The Wayback Machine – Internet Archive Help Center](https://help.archive.org/hc/en-us/articles/360004651732-Using-The-Wayback-Machine)