# Should all posts use archival websites for external links?

Tags: discussion, hyperlinks, broken-link

If somebody links to a website in a question or answer and that website goes offline then the question or answer are useless for future use if it contained critical information.

Would it be better for future use if everybody used something like http://archive.is/ or https://web.archive.org/ for external links?

That way even when the main site goes offline the question and/or answer can still be used by somebody in the future.

Comment: It would be better to delete or edit every post that relies on external sources and move that stuff into the post itself.

Comment: For the record, the Tom in the comments and the Tom that asked this question are not the same.

Comment: @M-Chen-3 After the OP commented, this adds to the confusion a little :) Also for the record: the question author's name is displayed over a greyish background in comments.

Comment: I voted to reopen as suggested [duplicate](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388449/automated-link-archiving) is primarily about adding such information automatically to comments (which are ok to have just links - i.e. for OP to properly incorporate to the question), while this one is about posts where links are expected to be optional and should not contain critical details of the question or the answer.

Comment: It's a reasonable question, but it's a bad idea, as explained in the answers. So don't be surprised if you get a few downvotes.

Answer (score 19):

> ... then the question or answer are useless for future use if it contained critical information.

Actually, the site is designed so that these kinds of questions and answers are not allowed. It is required for posts to be self contained. If they rely on external resources for critical information, the post should be edited to include that information within the post itself. If a post cannot be, or is not, edited to be self contained, they are typically closed (and possibly deleted) in the case of questions, and deleted in the case of answers.

In general, a post is supposed to be useful even if the link dies, and so requiring that the links work in perpetuity is largely pointless. There's nothing wrong with providing a link that is guaranteed to work forever, but that's just a nice touch, and there's no real benefit to requiring it.

Note that there are some questions for which a link *is* the answer. In those cases, the link dying is actually valuable information, and so there's nothing wrong with the link not working in the future.

Answer (score 10):

Your question contains the hidden premise that answers and questions are allowed to rely on external resources. This is not the case. Every question and answer must be self-contained. Links to external resources should always act as additional information, e.g. "nice-to-know" information or links for quotation/copyright, but nothing that is essential for the answer or question itself.

The reason is exactly what you've described in your question: Links can break and if an answer or question relies on it, it breaks too. How reliable the external resource is, should not be too important here. If you see such a post, ask the author via comment to edit essential information into the post.

Comment: Sometimes those posts are over 5 years old and the author is no longer active.

Comment: @Tom Then do it yourself. Feel free to participate in curation of this site.

Comment: I would if that site that was linked in those posts was still available, but sometimes they aren't and there isn't anything that can be done about it.

Comment: It's often possible to find backups of such sites, especially if it's a notable link, that *already* exist on archive/ way back machine. Worth a look if you come across a dead link that added anything of value.

Comment: @Tom That's unfortunate, but it's how it is. Handle such posts as what they are. If one became completely useless, flag it. If one is nearly useless, downvote it.

Comment: @Tom - can you provide a specific example of such a post?

Comment: @oleg Valter Not atm, but I come across them sporadically.

Comment: @Tom come on, it took a couple of minutes to find from your suggested edit history: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/28207472. You salvaged the link, and the poster already made sure the answer is self-contained by reposting the code, so the system worked exactly as intended :)

Answer (score 5):

Browsing through archive.org copies of sites is slower and less nice than accessing the original site, so no, hurting the common case (usability of the current link) and making more work for people writing answers would not be a good idea.

The slight benefit is saving work finding an archive.org copy of a link and editing it into posts if the doc / blog / whatever that a post referenced for further reading disappears at some point in the future.  Most things that are linked from SO answers are already indexed by archive.org so there's generally no need to pre-emptively make sure they're archived when you write the answer.

SO has a good history of not allowing answers that are link-only, so while it's common for answers to contain links for more details, they're not (supposed to be) essential, so the downside is just some future editing needed.  Most posts that just have a link are pretty questionable and could get deleted now, unless they're old answers to old questions that we choose not to delete because the link is so good.  (Comments are the current place for useful-link suggestions that don't go with a proper answer.)

Comment: "more work for people" might be reduced by [Automatic creation of Internet Archive Wayback Machine links for external links](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/397687/11942268).

Comment: @Thomas: Yes, that would be good for links that have gone dead.  Triggering a wayback snapshot of the current URL when the answer is posted would also be useful, to make sure it's there for automated replacement if it dies in the future.  I still would *not* want it for all external links in answers automatically, though.  Worse mouseover experience for seeing the URL, and worse browsing experience.